# Tika unable to parse after detecting mime-type

Tags: java, apache-tika, text-extraction

I have earlier succeeded in parsing all kinds of files with Tika by calling `tika.parseToString()` without setting any custom configuration or metadata. Now I have the need to filter files to parse based on mime-type.

I can find the mime-type with `tika.detect(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream), new Metadata());`, but when calling `tika.parseToString()` afterwards tika uses EmptyParser and the content-type detected is "application/octet-stream". This is default, meaning that tika is unable to find what type of file it is. I have tried to set the content type in Metadata before trying to parse the file, but this leads to `org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOException`. From what I've read this means that the file is malformed, but the same files gets parsed successfully without the check for mime-type beforehand.

Does detect() do something with the InputStream, making the parser unable to parse the files?

I'm using the same tika-instance for both checking the mime-type and parsing, version 1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was caused by passing InputStream to the parse method directly. detect() marks and resets the stream passed, which InputStream does not support. Wrapping the InputStream into a TikaInputStream(`TikaInputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));`) solved the issue.